# How to use Azure Data Factory to Unpivot json documents to SQL Database

Tags: json, business-intelligence, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-sql-database

I need to copy data from DocumentDB to Azure SQL Database.

Json documents are like this:

{

"DeviceID": "D1",

"Time": "2017-07-27T20:00:00",

"Temperature": 25,

"Humedity": 50

}

Destination SQL database table structure is (DeviceID | SensorID | Value | Time)
So data is like this:

## DeviceID    |    SensorID    |    Value    |       Time

```
D1      |  Temperature   |      25     | 2017-07-27 20:00:00 
D1      |  Humedity      |      50     | 2017-07-27 20:00:00
```

Now how to implement that??

I thought to change the Json document structure to have a list of SensorIDs and Values, it may be a bad design but also Data Factory refused it, as list columns are not supported

I'm thinking now to create a structured table like this (DeviceID | Temperature | Humedity  | Time) and use ADF to copy data to it, then copy data again from it to my table using SQL's UNPIVOT clause.

Any help to achive the right/best implementation??

Comment: See the [FAQ on "What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Avoid asking subjective questions. This question doesn't have a 'right' answer.

Answer (score 2):

Within SQL Azure and SQL Server's Engine:
You can use OPENJSON to convert this into a relational form.  Then you can use the SQL PIVOT operator to pivot it for rows into columns:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

So, you can land the JSON within SQL and then convert it.

There may be other paths within ADF that work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The data factory documentation on first sight doesn't make it obvious that it can map columns built in.

Data factory has native support for Json, by specifying the type of data set to be json and defining it's structure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-supported-file-and-compression-formats#json-format

I'd recommend playing with the copy wizard in the portal to get you familiar with how data factory works.

You can then map columns using [TabularTranslator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-map-columns)

Comment: The first URL covers the case of Blop as a datasoruce, but I'm using DocumentDB as a datasoruce.

I think something like "jsonPathDefinition" helps very well but it is not supported for DocumentDB.